# Get min price id without inner select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `a` with this data:

```
+-----+-----------+-------+
|  id | parent_id | price |
+-----+-----------+-------+
|   1 |         1 |   100 |
|   2 |         1 |   200 |
|   3 |         1 |    99 |
|   4 |         2 |  1000 |
|   5 |         2 |   999 |
+-----+-----------+-------+
```

I want to get the `id` of min pirce for each parent_id.
There is any way to get this result without subquery?

```
+-----+-----------+-------+
|  id | parent_id | price |
+-----+-----------+-------+
|   3 |         1 |    99 |
|   5 |         2 |   999 |
+-----+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: just curious as to why no inner select (subquery) is allowed, it would be easiest way to solve...

Comment: I think you will need either a JOIN or a subquery.  What do you mean by "without inner select", you do not want to use a subquery?

Comment: Because AFAIK the subquery is slower, and I wanted to know is there any faster or cleaner way to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a shot at how to do it without subqueries. I haven't tested, let me know if it works!

```
SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, t.price
FROM table t
LEFT JOIN table t2
  ON (t.parent_id = t2.parent_id AND t.price > t2.price)
GROUP BY t.id, t.parent_id, t.price
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND max(t2.price) is null
ORDER BY t.parent_id, t.price desc;
```

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, I've seen similar queries elsewhere, this type is good for top k per group...very fast too since subqueries actually do kill performance

Comment: Note that you will get multiple rows per parent_id if entries with the same price exist.

Comment: @nrainer this is true, but there is no information from the OP on how to consolidate ties and there is no obvious way either

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT D1.id, D1.parent_id, D1.price
FROM Data D1
LEFT JOIN Data D2 on D2.price < D1.price AND D1.parent_id = D2.parent_id
WHERE D2.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.id,T2.parent_id,T2.price FROM
(SELECT id,price
 FROM TableName) T1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT parent_id,MIN(price) as price
FROM TableName
GROUP BY parent_id) T2 ON T1.price=T2.price
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbb0a/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try group by,

```
SELECT parent_id,min(price)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY parent_id
```

Comment: this won't give the id field

Comment: He needs the `id` of the row with min_price as well.

Comment: @Log1c: I am really sorry, my friend. Changed to your previous answer. God! I really need some coffee.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT a.id, a.parent_id, a.price
FROM a
LEFT JOIN a AS b ON b.price < a.price AND b.parent_id = a.parent_id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Find the results at this fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09c888/10

Comment: This is this same as Sam's answer, but with a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can try this without using any join or subquery you will surely get the desired result.

SELECT TOP 2 FROM a ORDER BY price